got `xdr processing error: xdr value invalid` error for soroban-examples project
I'm just trying the demo from here.
After download, I cd into the "increment" project.
It builds, deploys and run successfully:
[12:20:33] ubuntu@wang /mnt/volume2/coding/stellar_/soroban-examples/increment [main]
(increment) ❱❱❱ soroban contract invoke \
  --id CD22GTHMWRIRVYJI55CAGSYGTMA6KTBESNU7D4NAEDBNUJIT47JSNYMU \
  --source alice \
  --network testnet \
  -- \
  increment
1

But, if I make a small change to the increment/src/lib.rs file, I change  count += 1;  to  count += 2;, then it throws an error xdr value invalid, but will succeed if I try more times.
(increment) ❱❱❱ soroban contract deploy \
>   --wasm target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/soroban_increment_contract.wasm \
>   --source alice \
>   --network testnet
error: xdr processing error: xdr value invalid

However, I always get  xdr value invalid error when running invoke:
(increment) ❱❱❱ soroban contract invoke \
  --id CAYX5EUZQEN2EH2XV7VNA7WUHOPRODXGAN6C4LRHGSX7DFEH7QJGRGS7 \
  --source alice \
  --network testnet \
  -- \
  increment
error: xdr processing error: xdr value invalid

(increment) ❱❱❱ soroban contract invoke \
  --id CAYX5EUZQEN2EH2XV7VNA7WUHOPRODXGAN6C4LRHGSX7DFEH7QJGRGS7 \
  --source alice \
  --network testnet \
  -- \
  --help
error: xdr processing error: xdr value invalid

My environment info:
(increment) ❱❱❱ rustc --version
rustc 1.78.0 (9b00956e5 2024-04-29)

[16:47:01] ubuntu@wang /mnt/volume2/coding/stellar/soroban-examples/increment [main]
(increment) ❱❱❱ soroban --version
soroban 20.3.4 (f30a47fc58ace4437b0252919420838550481420)
soroban-env 20.3.0 (befdf4b2b6061bd6da20b0f93d539d6ad8d8be22)
soroban-env interface version 85899345920
stellar-xdr 20.1.0 (8b9d623ef40423a8462442b86997155f2c04d3a1)
xdr curr (b96148cd4acc372cc9af17b909ffe4b12c43ecb6)

[16:47:39] ubuntu@wang /mnt/volume2/coding/stellar/soroban-examples/increment [main]
(increment) ❱❱❱ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/ubuntu/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
solana

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (overridden by '/mnt/volume2/coding/stellar/soroban-examples/rust-toolchain.toml')
rustc 1.78.0 (9b00956e5 2024-04-29)

[16:47:58] ubuntu@wang /mnt/volume2/coding/stellar/soroban-examples/increment [main]
(increment) ❱❱❱ cat ../rust-toolchain.toml
[toolchain]
channel = "stable"
targets = ["wasm32-unknown-unknown"]
components = ["rustc", "cargo", "rustfmt", "clippy", "rust-src"]


My colleague also tried on his MacBook and got the same issue as me.

I encountered the same error when using soroban-cli v20.3.4.
The issue went away after I re-built the same contract with the most recent version of soroban-cli listed here.
$ cargo install --locked --version 21.0.0-rc.1 soroban-cli


Since the stellar protocol has been updated cargo install --locked --version 21.0.0-rc.1 soroban-cli might not work and you will probably keep getting the same error. Try cargo install stellar-cli@22.0.0-rc.1 and it should work. Keep in touch with Stellar's protocol updates and follow the discord channel for updates and solutions.
For this solution click here
